# Comma getting attached to the gridview textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, modalpopupextender

I have a gridview binding to viewstate, viewstate holds a datatable. In the gridview I have EditItemTemplates.

When i click a Done button, modalpopup shows,

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
   mdlPopup.Show();
 }

protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mdlPopup.Hide();       
}
```

whenever a postback happens, the data in the gridview textboxes gets repeated with a comma appended.

I have the Javascripts:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
          //http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Max-length-for-multiline-textbox-in-asp-net
          function Check(textBox, maxLength) {
              if (textBox.value.length > maxLength) {
                  alert("You cannot enter more than " + maxLength + " characters.");
                  textBox.value = textBox.value.substr(0, maxLength);
              }

          }

    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.onkeydown = Esc;
        function Esc() {
            var KeyID = event.keyCode;
            if (KeyID == 27) {
                if ($find("mdlPopup")) {
                    $find("mdlPopup").hide();
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Gridview to HTML code:

```
 public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET
       server control at run time. */
    return;
}
private string getHTML(GridView gv)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter textwriter = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter htmlwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(textwriter);
    gv.RenderControl(htmlwriter);
    htmlwriter.Flush();
    textwriter.Flush();
    htmlwriter.Dispose();
    textwriter.Dispose();
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I have no Idea from where the comma gets attached to the text in the textbox.

Can anyone help me out doing this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you use `Javascript` ?

Comment: yes, only to limit the characters of the gridview textbox and to close the popup on Esc key pressed

Comment: it's better if you show me your `Javascript` :)

Comment: I have found that converting gridview to HTML code is creating the commas. But how do i solve it? I will update the converting code in the Question

Comment: @Shanna, did you figure this out?